# Displaying multiple tables using Package officer and flextable

Tags: r, function, flextable, officer, reporters

I was wondering if it might be possible to display more than one `flextable` in the HTML format (on a single page) using `flextable` and `officer`?

```
 library('flextable')
 library('officer')

dat1 <- data.frame(Approaches = c("Y", "Y", "N"), Meets = c("N", "Y", "N"), row.names = c("Read", "Math", "Sci."))
dat2 <- data.frame(Read = "Y", Math = "N")

def_par <- fp_par(text.align = "center")
def_txt <- fp_text(bold = TRUE)


ft <- flextable(dat1, cwidth = c(3.2, 3.2))      # Table #1

ft <- style(ft, pr_p = def_par, part = "all")
ft <- style(ft, pr_t = def_txt, part = "header")

tit <- c("Domain 1 and Domain 2B", "Domain 2A")

ft <- set_caption(ft, tit[1])

ft <- add_footer_lines(ft, values = "") # add a line break

flextable(dat2, cwidth = c(3.2, 3.2))            # Table #2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done easily in a rmarkdown document

````
---
title: "test"
author: "akrun"
date: "12/18/2019"
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
library('officer')
library(flextable)

```


```{r echo=FALSE, results='asis'}
library(htmltools)
dat1 <- data.frame(Approaches = c("Y", "Y", "N"), Meets = c("N", "Y", "N"), row.names = c("Read", "Math", "Sci."))
dat2 <- data.frame(Read = "Y", Math = "N")

def_par <- fp_par(text.align = "center")
def_txt <- fp_text(bold = TRUE)


ft <- flextable(dat1, cwidth = c(3.2, 3.2))      # Table #1

ft <- style(ft, pr_p = def_par, part = "all")
ft <- style(ft, pr_t = def_txt, part = "header")

tit <- c("Domain 1 and Domain 2B", "Domain 2A")

ft <- set_caption(ft, tit[1])

ft <- add_footer_lines(ft, values = "") # 
ft

```


```{r echo=FALSE, results='asis'}
ft2 <- flextable(dat2, cwidth = c(3.2, 3.2)) 
ft2 <- style(ft2, pr_p = def_par, part = "all")
ft2 <- style(ft2, pr_t = def_txt, part = "header")

tit <- c("Read", "Math")
ft2 <- set_caption(ft2, tit[1])
ft2 <- add_footer_lines(ft2, values = "") # 
ft2
```
````

-output

[image]

---

In `R studio`, first create a markdown document (File -> New File -> R markdown ..),

[image]

Paste the above code in the document, save it in a file/folder and then click on `knit`
[image]

Comment: Thanks, but I'm sure when working with `flextable` there is a way to directly get 2 tables in one HTML without using knitr. But I have upvoted your kind effort here.

Comment: Akrun, by any chance, do you know how to add a new column to the left of these tables?

Comment: @rnorouzian Can't it be created with all the columns